# Get a list of Monday dates from Broadcast calender between given range of dates using java

Tags: java, date, calendar, java-time

I have a date range Oct 7, 2024 to Dec 29, 2024. I need to fetch all the weeks start date of a broadcast calendar that is all Monday dates between this range. Trying to do something like below. I'm only able to get start of one date would like to extend this to fetch me list of all Monday dates. Oct 7
Oct 14
Oct 21
Oct 28
Nov 4
Nov 11
Nov 18
Nov 25
Dec 02
Dec 09
Dec 16
Dec 23

```
 @Test
public void toBroadcastStartDate() {
    Date dateFormate = new Date("Nov 05, 2024 12:00 AM EST");
    BroadcastCalendar broadcastCalendar = new BroadcastCalendar();
    LocalDate broadcastStartDate = broadcastCalendar.getWeekStart(Instant.ofEpochMilli(dateFormate.getTime()).atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toLocalDate());
    System.out.println("check here "+Date.from(broadcastStartDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()));
}
```

Comment: If your class gives you the start of the week (presumably a Monday) as a `LocalDate` then what's the problem with calling `plusDays(7)` on it? Don't mix in datetime objects from `java.util` btw

Comment: I have an range end date as well, so is there a way to give it before Dec 29, 2024 instead of just adding 7 days

Comment: Well what's wrong with looping and getting out at the right time?

Comment: I strongly recommend that you avoid the `Date` class. It was poorly designed and is therefore long outdated. Even if you insisted on `Date`, definitely stay far away from its `Date(String)` constructor. It’s magical in the bad, unpredictable way, and its been deprecated for more than 25 years. Use for example `ZonedDateTime.parse("Nov 05, 2024 12:00 AM EST", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, uuuu h:mm a zzz", Locale.ROOT)).toLocalDate()` to get your `LocalDate` from your string. It’s also simpler, saves quite some conversion trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Stream.iterate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate(T,java.util.function.Predicate,java.util.function.UnaryOperator)) you could do this:

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse("Oct 7, 2024", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d, yyyy"));
LocalDate end   = LocalDate.parse("Dec 29, 2024", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d, yyyy"));

Stream
    .iterate(
        start , 
        localDate -> localDate.isBefore(end), 
        localDate -> localDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY))
    )
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 3):

### `LocalDate#datesUntil`

In Java 9+, calling [`LocalDate#datesUntil`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#datesUntil(java.time.LocalDate,java.time.Period)) provides a [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) of `LocalDate` objects.

If you are aware that your start day is a monday you could do the following.

```
var start = LocalDate.of(2024, 10, 7);
var end = LocalDate.of(2024, 12, 29);
        
var mondays = start.datesUntil(end, Period.ofWeeks(1)).toList();
System.out.println(mondays);
```

Comment: Thanks Karsten, but is datesUntil method from java9? we are at java8 can you help with something different. And the start day and end day  can be any day of the week.

Comment: @raj In Java 8 you’ll need to use one of the solutions in the other Answers. The `datesUntil` method arrived in Java 9.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on **Java 8**, you could simply loop until your current date matches or exceeds the end date. Something like this:

```java
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2024, 10, 7);
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2024, 12, 29);
List<LocalDate> mondays = new ArrayList<>();
LocalDate monday = startDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
while (monday.isBefore(endDate) || monday.isEqual(endDate)) {
      mondays.add(monday);
      monday = monday.plusDays(7);
}
```

Now `mondays` contains all Mondays between 2024-10-07 and 2024-12-29 (inclusive).

Comment: Can you help with this scenario, incase Oct 06,2024(Sunday) is start date, It should return Sep 30(monday)

Comment: @raj just remove the call to TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(): LocalDate monday = startDate.with(DayOfWeek.MONDAY);. It will always jump to the previous Monday unless the date in question is Monday.